# Clarification of the analysis of the worst case situation of quicksort as dealt with in CLRS

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, quicksort

I was going through the text Introduction to Algorithms by Cormen et. al. and I came across their analysis of the worst case of the quicksort algorithm. I could not quite understand a few specific statements used by them.

*I try to bring up the excerpts from the text with the portions where I face difficulty and the portions are marked with $*$ , $\quad\dagger$ , $\quad\dagger\dagger$, $\quad\ddagger$, $\quad\ddagger\ddagger$*.

Situation of the text (in brief): In section say $A$ of the text the authors try to convince us about the worst case situation of quick sort and then in section say $B$ the authors formally try to analyze the situation.

### Section $A$

---

> **Worst-case partitioning**
>
> The worst-case behavior for quicksort occurs when the partitioning routine produces one subproblem with $n - 1$ elements and one with $0$ elements. (We prove this claim in Section $B$ $^\dagger$) Let us assume that this unbalanced partitioning arises in each recursive call. The partitioning costs $\Theta(n)$ time. Since the recursive call on an array of size $0$ just returns, $T(0)=\Theta(1)$, and the recurrence for the running time is
>
> $T(n) = T(n - 1)+ T(0) + \Theta(n)= T(n - 1)+ \Theta(n) \tag 1$

Which can be easily solved using iterations or substitution and the answer turns out to be $T(n)=\Theta(n^2)$

> Thus, if the partitioning is maximally$^*$ unbalanced at every recursive level of the algorithm, the running time is $\Theta(n^2)$.

*$*$ By the use of the term maximal I hope they mean that there are no other unbalanced partition which is more unbalanced than the maximal unbalanced partition, which therefore means that the maximal unbalanced partition is that of $0$ and $n-1$. And they probably mean that **the worst case situation occurs $\text{uniquely}$ only in this particular situation.*** $^{\ddagger\ddagger}$

### Section $B$

---

> Let $T(n)$ be the worst-case time for the procedure QUICKSORT on an input of size $n$. We have the recurrence
>
> $$T(n) = \max_{0\leq q \leq n-1} (T(q) + T(n - q - 1))+ \Theta(n) \tag 2$$
>
> where the parameter $q$ ranges from $0$ to $n - 1$ because the procedure PARTITION produces two subproblems with total size $n - 1$. We guess that $T(n)\leq cn^2$ for some constant $c$. Substituting this guess into recurrence, we obtain
>
> $$T(n) \leq \max_{0\leq q \leq n-1} (cq^2 + c(n - q - 1)^2)+ \Theta(n)$$
>
> $$= c .\max_{0\leq q \leq n-1} (q^2 + (n - q - 1)^2)+ \Theta(n)$$

The expression $q^2 + (n - q - 1)^2$ (where $q$ is the parameter) achieves its maximum for the values $q= 0,n-1$. (It can be easily shown by calculus)

**I hope that this is the prove that the *worst case situation occurs uniquely* only in the particular case when the unbalancing partitions the array into two subarrays of size $0$ and $n-1$. ( The authors do not say it explicitly though in $\dagger$ of Section $A$)** $^{\dagger\dagger}$

In either case the of the maxima of $q$ the maximum value of the expression is $(n-1)^2$ which on incorporating in place of $max$ in the solution of the recurrence we have,

> $$T(n) \leq c.(n-1)^2 + \Theta(n) \leq cn^2$$, for some large enough $c$ (details not shown)
>
> So, $T(n)= O(n^2)$
>
> We saw in Section $A$ a speciﬁc$^\ddagger$ case in which quicksort takes $\Omega(n^2)$ time: when partitioning is unbalanced. Alternatively,we can show that for the recurrence $(2)$, $T(n)=\Omega(n^2)$.$^\|$

---

**Doubts:**

***"We saw in Section $A$ a speciﬁc case in which quicksort takes $\Omega(n^2)$ time: when partitioning is unbalanced. Alternatively,we can show that for the recurrence $(2)$,  $T(n)=\Omega(n^2)$."***

It is this last line which sort of disturbs me.

$\ddagger$ : First of all in the section $A$ of the book only one example is given of the unbalanced partition which I feel from the proof ($\dagger\dagger$) is the *only situation* ($\ddagger\ddagger$) in which the worst case situation occurs and they are referring to this very example.

$(1)$ Suppose that I am wrong and there are more than one possible situation where the worst case scenario occurs (i.e. my claim in $\dagger\dagger$ and $\ddagger\ddagger$ are incorrect)... Then the authors have found in section $B$ that $T(n)= O(n^2)$ then just analyzing a single particular situation (the example they are talking about in section $A$) as running in $\Omega(n^2)$ does not make us conclude that $T(n)=\Theta(n^2)$, we need to show this lower bound for all possible candidate of worst case situation...

$(2)$ Suppose if I am right and there is only one possibility of splitting in the worst case (i.e. my claim in $\dagger\dagger$ and $\ddagger\ddagger$ are correct)... Then the authors have found in section $B$ that $T(n)= O(n^2)$ for the $\text{unique worst case}$ ($\dagger\dagger$ and $\ddagger\ddagger$) which was already proved to have $T(n)=\Theta(n^2)$ in section $A$. Using the $\Omega$ (i.e lower bounding situation) part of $\Theta$ which was proved in section $A$ ***why*** proof $\Theta$ for the recurrence in $B$ again ? ... It is definitely weird. We can simply use the recurrence $(2)$ and use substitution and find that $T(n)=\Omega(n^2)$ (which is probably what the authors say at the very end).

Which of the alternatives $(1)$ or $(2)$ is correct?

Comment: could you clarify what you are asking, briefly? Are you asking if Quicksort's average runtime is different from its worst-case runtime? Are you asking about when Quicksort's runtime is of the order $O(n^2)$? Or are you asking something specific about the excerpts provided?

Comment: There are 2^n or so permutations with worst possible behaviour, if for each of n partitions the pivot is either the smallest or the largest element.

Comment: I am updating my question making it clearer...

Comment: @gnasher729 so does the thing ultimately boil down to fact that worst case situation is unique as far as the partitioning is concerned?: a partition of $0$ and another of $n-1$ in an unordered manner ( note: I am not saying about a unique permutation, I am saying about the unique partition size of the sub-array when input array is of size $n$)

Comment: I’d say that the worst case is absolutely not unique - picking the smallest or the largest element as the pivot gives extremely different behaviour of the algorithm. The array will be rearranged in a very different way.

Comment: @gnasher729 That why I am having problem with this excerpt.  The authors seem to assume (I feel so after reading, might be wrong though) that the worst case condition occurs in a unique situation irrespective of the permutation but only depending on the size of sub-array and depending on whether this claim is true or not, the last two queries 1 and 2 under doubts has an answer. A well compiled answer removing all my problems .. this is what I am waiting for. Thanks anyways.